# Working of Iterator of Collections framework in java

Tags: java, collections, iterator

The objective is to take inputs from the user and add a string "###" in the code itself and then again add some string. The objective is to print the inputs that is taken  after adding "###".
The code is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    static Iterator func(ArrayList mylist)
    {
        Iterator it=mylist.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Object element = it.next();
            if(element instanceof String) { 
                break;
            }
        }
        return it;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String []argh)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int m=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            mylist.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        mylist.add("###");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            mylist.add(sc.next());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator it=func(mylist);
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Object element = it.next();
            System.out.println((String)element);
        }
    }
}
```

> The input is:

```
2 2
42
10
hello
java
```

> The output is:

```
hello 
java
```

My question is how only hello and java are printed here because the while loop breaks at the first encounter of the String "###"(which we added in the code).

*can somebody explain this?*

Answer (score 1):

```
 Object element = it.next();
 if(element instanceof String) { 
    break;
 }
```

In the above code snippet, it will get the first `String` `element`, and at the same time, the iterator will go to next and skip the first `String` element.

So the "###" will be ignored, because it is the first `String` type element.

Comment: got it! Thanks a ton!